# GAE, "no matching index found" as result of query

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, intellij-idea, jpql

First of all my application works on local server while it doesn't work when I pushed it to production server!!!

I spent 2 hours and found something with my Entity class has problem but I didn't find what. I also guess maybe my query has problem. So, this is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "UserAppsJPA")
public class UserAppsJPA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String packageName;
    private String userUUID;
    private String appName;
    private long appCounter;
    private long appUsage;
    private long installDate;
    private long uninstallDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserAppsJPA that = (UserAppsJPA) o;

        if (!packageName.equals(that.packageName)) return false;
        if (!userUUID.equals(that.userUUID)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = packageName.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + userUUID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserAppsJPA {" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", packageName='" + packageName + '\'' +
                ", userUUID='" + userUUID + '\'' +
                ", appName='" + appName + '\'' +
                ", appCounter=" + appCounter +
                ", appUsage=" + appUsage +
                ", installDate=" + installDate +
                ", uninstallDate=" + uninstallDate +
                '}';
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

// other setters and getters methods

}
```

Compose of `packageName` and `userUUID` is enough for making private key however I found it's difficult to me (as I'm super junior in GAE). That's why I added `id` field in this class.

I have defined following line as my query string in servlet class:

```
private static final String QUERY_USER_APPS   = "SELECT m FROM UserAppsJPA m WHERE m.packageName = :keywordPkg AND m.userUUID = :keywordUUID ORDER BY m.appName ASC";
```

and finally my method:

```
private void updateUserTable(List<UserAppsJPA> userAppsJPAList) {
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

        try {
            for (int i=0; i<userAppsJPAList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("=> " + i + " - " + userAppsJPAList.get(i).toString());
                Query q = em.createQuery(QUERY_USER_APPS)
                        .setParameter("keywordPkg", userAppsJPAList.get(i).getPackageName())
                        .setParameter("keywordUUID", userAppsJPAList.get(i).getUserUUID());

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<UserAppsJPA> list = (List<UserAppsJPA>) q.getResultList(); // <= I guess problem is here
                if(list == null)
                    System.out.println("list is null");
                else
                    System.out.println("3-1, size: " + list.size());
                if(list != null  &&  list.size()>0) {
                    UserAppsJPA record = list.get(0);
                    userAppsJPAList.get(i).setId(record.getId());
                }
                System.out.println("@@@");
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.persist(userAppsJPAList.get(i));
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error => " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned above code is working on local machine while doesn't work on production server. This is log:

```
2014-02-20 17:12:03.509

[s~twitterjaya-eyeballs/1.373900386032203857].<stdout>: => 0 - UserAppsJPA {id=null, packageName='com.twitterjaya.eyeball', userUUID='00000000-74f7-8968-ffff-fffff607c160', appName='Eyeball', appCounter=17, appUsage=3060000, installDate=1392879894412, uninstallDate=0}

I 2014-02-20 17:12:03.518

[s~twitterjaya-eyeballs/1.373900386032203857].<stdout>: Error => no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="UserAppsJPA" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="packageName" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="userUUID" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="appName" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

I guess my entity shouldn't have problem because it's similar to my other entity which is working. Therefore, I'm suspicious to query string.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add that index and upload it to production, as the error says.

Comment: Thanks Tim, would you please give me more detail. thanks

Comment: What you need to add is listed in the error. How you add that and deploy will require you reading the docs. I don't do java on appengine.

Comment: let me search about it... thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) follow these instructions:

1. Navigate to you PROJECT-DIRECTORY/out/artifacts/
2. Open `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` into an editor (drag&drop it into IntelliJ IDEA for example)
3. Add your indexes
4. Rebuild your project and push it to server
5. Go to your `control panel` and then `Datastore Indexes`, you see your indexes are under building. Wait 1-2 minutes and refresh the page. When it changed to `Serving` your API is ready

Mine is here:

```
<datastore-indexes>

    <!-- *** This one generated wrong by GAE that's why you should do it manually ***
    <datastore-index kind="UserAppsJPA" ancestor="false" source="auto">
        <property name="userUUID" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="appCounter" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index> -->

    <datastore-index kind="UserAppsJPA" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="packageName" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="userUUID" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

</datastore-indexes>
```

Read [Index configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration) for more information.

Special thanks to @Tim for his suggestion.